# How I can Use IUserIdPriver? where am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, chat, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working in asp.net core mvc signalr project. I want to send message to specific user. I read many article about this and look at the some solution about this problem in stackoverflow but still I cant do this. I wanna send message to user use User's email which is stored in database instead of unique connection id. How can I fill this methods? I cant fill.
This is my hubclass

```
 public class SignalRChat:Hub
    {

       
        public async Task ClientSendMessage(string connectionId,string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage",user, message);
        }
       

        public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {

            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("connected", Context.ConnectionId);
            
          
        }

    }
```

This is my CustomProvider class

```
 public class CustomProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

This is js code

```
"use strict";


$(document).ready(() => {
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chathub").build();
    connection.on("connected", connecitonid => $("#connectionId").html(connecitonid));

    connection.start();

    $("button").click(() => {
        let message = $("#txtMessage").val();
        var user = $("#sender").val();
        connection.invoke("ClientSendMessage", $("#client").val(),user, message)
            .catch(error => console.log("Error." + error));
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.textContent = "me" + ":" + message;
        document.getElementById("son").appendChild(div);
    });

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
        var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
        var encodedMsg = user + ":" + msg;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.textContent = encodedMsg;
        document.getElementById("son").appendChild(div);
        
    });

});
```

This is html code

```
 <div id="chat" style="display:none;margin-left:30%;">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"><h5>Connection ID : <span id="connectionId"></span></h5></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7"><input type="text" id="sender" value="Sender Name"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7"><input type="text" placeholder="ReceiverId" id="client"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7"> <input type="text" id="txtMessage"> <button>Send</button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7" id="son"> </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        
        
    </div>
```

And this is how codes appear
[I dont want this id I wanna use email adress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0i7y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should read the docs about using Users: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0#users-in-signalr

Basically, you would use the Email claim in your custom `IUserIdProvider` and then use `Clients.User(user).SendAsync(...)` when sending to that email.

Comment: how can I edit js file and hub class according to your advice?